# How to match a submatch prefix in a regular expression in c++11?

Tags: c++, regex, string, c++11

I have a very simple question, but I can't figure out the answer.

I have a suffix string and I want to extract the prefix of the substring if it ends with the suffix using c++ regular expressions and submatch.

For e.g.;
if I have a string "abc def" and my regex is "(.+) def"; I want to return "abc":-

However, when I try to compute it using sub_match function, I get  the entire string "abc def". Here's my code :-

```
int main() {
  regex pattern("(.+) def");
  smatch a;
  string s = "pqr def";
  bool b = regex_match(s, a, pattern);
  cout << a.size() << a[0] << ";" << a[1] << ";";
}

Output :-
2pqr def;pqr def;
```

thanks,
Amit

Comment: Using your code I don't get your output. I get this: `2pqr def;pqr;`. What compiler/version?

Comment: g++ -std=c++11 t1.cpp. It's weird. I get different output using Steephen's  suggestion as well.

Comment: But what compiler version? `g++ --version` GCC didn't fully implement `<regex>` until `v4.9.0`.

Comment: aah, probably that's the reason. v4.8.

Comment: Yup 4.8 is completely broken for regex.

Comment: @AmitGupta The solution to your problem is upgrade to gcc 4.9 or newer. Seems like this question should therefore be closed.